# Wifi not detected in Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless, kubuntu, dell

I just finished installing Kubuntu 18.04 on my brand new Dell XPS 13, but the wifi card doesn't seem to be recognized. The tray icon only shows the wired connection.

`iwconfig` output:

`lo    no wireless extenstions.
enx9xxxxxxx  no wireless extensions.`

`lspci -nn | grep -i Net` output:

`02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)`

Now the other problem is that I don't have a way of even creating a wired connection as the laptop doesn't have a network port on it.

I checked the BIOS and Secure Boot has already been disabled.

Any tips?

Comment: does `ubuntu-drivers devices`     "backport-iwlwifi-dkms - distro free" available for your intel card? I have the same card with `rev 3a` and it shows as an availble driver for me.  It is to "allow the driver to be installed with older kernels". Doesn't how old but in 19.10 I don't need to install it to have may card work, maybe 18.04 is old enough.

Comment: if you see the driver available it might fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks @TrailRider. I ended up doing a simple system update using an ethernet cable and a USB adapter which resolved it